# C# listview optimum column width

Tags: c#, listview

I have a C# ListView and I'd like to autosize the column widths based on the contents of the column.

I know that setting the column width to -1 will size the column at the length of the widest member.
I know that setting the column width to -2 will size the column at the length of the column header.
How do I size the column to be the greater of the two?

I could do something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < listView.Columns.Count; ++i)
{
    listView.Columns[i].Width = -1;
    int width1 = listView.Columns[i].Width;
    listView.Columns[i].Width = -2;
    if (width1 > listView.Columns[i].Width)
        listView.Columns[i].Width = -1;
}
```

but it does seem fabulously inefficient.

Does anyone have an answer?

Comment: You could add the header content as a listview item, set it to -1 then remove the header element. Not sure if it would work though, and your idea is probably more efficient anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should try

```
ListView.AutoResizeColumns(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.HeaderSize);
```

even though it says "ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.HeaderSize" it should auto resize to the largest item in the column, whether it's the header or a column member

Comment: It seems to work, but the vertical line after the last column is removed. Not acceptable. At least not to me.